# Get specific UIBezierPath that contains target CGPoint

Tags: swift, uikit, uibezierpath, cgpoint

Is there any method that can determine whether a target `CGPoint` (from user touch) is inside of *any* `UIBezierPath` object?

I have an indoor map application. All my rooms are `UIBezierPath` objects. I need to detect whether the user touches on one of them?

I am aware that `UIBezierPath.contains(_:)` exists, and this would work well if I had a single `UIBezierPath` object, but I may have 10, 20, or even 100 `UIBezierPath` objects. **How can I efficiently check to see which path actually contains the point?**